# Validate a cluster profile with command lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parfor

I need to validate a cluster profile in Matlab. The [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/clusters-and-cluster-profiles.html#brrzq8d-1) just shows how to do so using the GUI:

[image]

That's nice but some Matlabs I use are on OSes without GUI. How can I validate a cluster profile with command lines only?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look inside the Validator class (example path for MATLAB 2014a):

```
..\MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\distcomp\cluster\+parallel\+internal\+validator\Validator.m
```

It shows exactly what's going on during the validation process. I'd suggest putting breakpoints inside the different methods and observing the passed-in data, or trying to find where they are called from and using which parameters.

On a side note, I found this file by putting breakpoints inside one of the functions mentioned in the GUI (see image) and then just stepping out:

- parcluster.m - \MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\distcomp\cluster
- createJob.m - \MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\distcomp\
- createCommunicatingJob.m - \MATLAB\R2014a\toolbox\distcomp\cluster+parallel\@Cluster

I hope this helps!

[image]